# What are the rules for placing & while using the split environment?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{\left(a,b\right) \mid \right.\left. a \in A, b \in B\right\}
\end{equation}
```

And I want to force specific line breaking and alignment using the `split` environment. When I try:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\{&\left(a,b\right) \mid \right. \\
&\left. a \in A, b \in B\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I get an error `Extra }, or forgotten \right \end{split}`

When I try:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\left\{\left(a,b\right) \mid \right. \\
&\left. a \in A, b \in B\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

it works fine. Why can't I align at whatever point I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `\left` and `\right` across`&` which limits the scope.

Also, it is not a good idea to use `\left` and `\right`, use `\big` brothers family from `amsmath`.  These need not be balanced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\{\right.&(a,b) \mid  \\
&\left. a \in A, b \in B\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\bigl\{&(a,b) \mid  \\
&{} a \in A, b \in \bigr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `\left` and `\right`, this may happen:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\{\right.&(a,b) \mid  \\
&\left. a \in A, b \in B\frac{A}{B}\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\biggl\{&(a,b) \mid  \\
&{} a \in A, b \in B \frac{A}{B}\biggr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]